# Capture dynamic input texbox values in the controller MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have html code in my cshtml file using MVC

```
 <table id="mylist">
      <tr>
         <td>
      <input type="text" id="list_0" name="list[0]">
         </td>
         <td>
      <input type="text" id="list_1" name="list[1]">
        </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

I have a button that dynamically adds a new tr with tds. After clicking submit button, in the controller, how do I get all the values from textboxes within the table? Is there an easier way to retrieve the values, so that I can save them in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path. Your dynamic text boxes should have `name` attribute set as you are already doing it. The model binder uses that for binding. Your model/ViewModel can look like below:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public string[] List { get; set; }
}
```

Then the controller will have action method like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(YourModel model)
{
     //you can access the text values like below:

     var listItems = model.List; 

     // your call to some services methods that saves these values
}
```

You can read more about model binding with arrays in [Scott Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) and model binding in general at this [MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)

Comment: Also note that the numbering must be sequential, so if you are dynamically deleting textboxes as well, you will need to ensure the names are in order before you post the values back to your controller.

Comment: Works. Can you pls clarify for me. I thought model binding uses the id attribute to match,am I wrong? so it always uses name? Thanks

Comment: @ChrisHardie In the simple scenario like this, ordering is optional. I have a lot of working without ordering. You can check Phil Haack's post for details http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: @Ben Glad, it works! :)  It goes by the name because Id attribute cannot be repeated. Otherwise, it will be invalid HTML. You will find Phil's post useful as well.